# Getting all decorators

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get all decorators within a directory? I'd like to implement a routing component which works the same way as in Symfony which uses Annotations:

```
@Route("/")
public function index() { // ...
```

So when starting up my application I need to find all annotations and create my routes out of it. Is this possible?

*edit*: Just to clarify: I'm talking about a NodeJS application. I want to iterate through all files in a directory and find all decorators.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all decorators within a directory"? Do you want to iterate over all files in a specific dir and then per file check for all it's decorators?  Is this even a node app or a browser one?

Comment: Yep, iterating through all files in a directory and check its decorators is exactly what I want. And we're talking about a NodeJS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to find/open the files (using `fs`) and then either parsing them yourself or use the [Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). Neither of those sound like much fun.

An alternative (in case I understand your scenario) is to register each component that is calling the decorator, something like:

```
const REGISTRY = new Map<string, Function[]>();
export function Route(path: string) {
    if (!REGISTRY.has(path)) {
        REGISTRY.set(path, []);
    }

    return (constructor: Function) => {
        REGISTRY.get(path).push(constructor);

        // do what ever the decorator does
    }
}
```

If this `Route` decorator isn't your but a part of a 3rd party library then use your own decorator which calls the original one.